# Add kafka path to /etc/environment file for kafka to be accessed globally. Add kafka path till bin folder

Tags: ubuntu, apache-kafka

I have to add kafka path to /etc/environment file for kafka to be accessed globally and also Add kafka path till bin folder .
Operating system is ubuntu
Please suggest on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open /etc/environment

```
1) vi /etc/environment
```

Add kafka home, extracted binary folder **kafka**

```
2) KAFKA_HOME="/kafka"
```

Set the path

```
3) PATH="$PATH:${KAFKA_HOME}/bin"
```